Electron app installation is finished, but it doesn't prompt anything after that
i've electron app that bundled using electron forge. By the way this app can run locally without no issue, i'm so confused.
even when i run the win32-x64 it got no issue.
But whenever i install the

squirrel/myapp.exe

version
It will prompted installation GIF loading and then finished. i can see my app on the search menu, but when i tried to open it doesnt really prompted anything.
Anyone know what is the issue ?
i'm bundle using command
npm run make


My bad guys,
i need to put package electron-log for logging on main.js
Also, my fault it because i download
package electron-is-dev only at devdependencies
by right it should be at dependencies, so will be available also after build

You don't need a package such as electron-is-dev, just use app.isPackaged
